# Implicit scala class with generics

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I have this code:

```
object Peek {
    implicit def traversableToPeek[A](underlying: Traversable[A]) = new Peek(underlying)
}
class Peek[A](underlying: Traversable[A]) {

    /**
     * Java-style peek method
     */
    def peek(func: A => Unit): Traversable[A] = {
        underlying.foreach(func)
        underlying
    }
}
```

while lets me write things like `List(1,2,3).peek(println).map(_+1).peek(println)` which prints 1,2,3 and then 2,3,4 (after `import Peek._`)

However, the compile-time value of that expression is `Traversable[Int]`.  This means that while this code compiles:

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
val l2 = 4 :: l
```

this code does not:

```
val l = List(1,2,3).peek(println)
val l2 = 4 :: l
```

since `::` is not defined on `Traversable`.  The intent of peek is to allow side-effect only operations without requiring somewhat ugly constructs like `l.map(e => println(e); e)`

I tried adding a second generic parameter `T <: Traversable` or `T[A] <: Traversable[A]` but could not get it compile in a manner where the implicit conversion worked.

I feel this should be possible, but I am not familiar enough with Scala to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second generic parameter is the correct approach:

```
implicit class Peek[C[X] <: Traversable[X], A](underlying: C[A]) {
  def peek(func: A => Unit): C[A] = {
    underlying.foreach(func)
    underlying
  }
}
```

(in Scala 2.13, replace deprecated `Traversable` with `Iterable`).

In case you have a type extending `Traversable[Something]` which isn't itself generic, the above won't work, but

```
implicit class Peek[C <: Traversable[A], A](underlying: C with Traversable[A]) {
  def peek(func: A => Unit): C = {
    underlying.foreach(func)
    underlying
  }
}
```

should.

Comment: We are still in Scala 2.12.

Comment: So the `X` is a type that only exists for define `C` fully?

Comment: Yes. You could write `C[A] <: Traversable[A]` with the same meaning but this would be a _different_ `A` from `Peek`'s own type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much difference than above, here is another alternative using `CanBuildFrom`

```scala
import scala.collection.generic._
import scala.language.higherKinds
implicit class CollWrapper[Coll[X] <: Traversable[X], A](coll:Coll[A]) {
    def peek(f:A => Unit)(implicit cbf:CanBuildFrom[Coll[A], A, Coll[A]]):Coll[A] = {
       val builder = cbf(coll)
       coll.foreach{elem =>
          builder += elem;
          f(elem)
       }
       coll
    }
}

List(1,2,3,4).peek(println).map(x => x * 3)
println("--")
List("One", "Two", "Three").peek(println).map(x => x + "!")
println("--")
List('c', 'd', 'e').peek(println).map(x => x + 3)
println("--")
Set("Nine", "Ten", "Twelve").peek(println).map(x => x + "!")
println("--")
Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two", 3 -> "Three").peek(println).map{case (k,v) => (k, v + "!")}.toMap
println("--")
```